# Swift - can only print object's memory address

Tags: ios, swift, api, rest, yelp

I'm using the Yelp API and pulling down a YLPBusiness. When I attempt to print() or dump() the YLPBusiness, I only receive the memory address in the console log.

If I print(YLPBusiness.name) however, I will receive the name. How can I fully print out all property values of the YLPBusiness object?

[image: Screen shot of code and console log]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override your class `description` property:

```
func description() -> String {
    return "Business name: \(self.name), address: \(self.address), etc."
}
```

where you print all properties of `YLPBusiness` as you desire.

You can fix your problem mentioned in comments by turning your method into property:

```
public override var description: String {
    return "Business name: \(self.name), address: \(self.address), etc."
}
```

It happened because Swift detects discrepancies between overloading and overriding in the Swift type system and the effective behavior seen via the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: That will solve it!  Thank you very much. You and Paulw11 both have the right ideas here. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: My pleasure to help. Consider accepting one answer, if it fits you needs.

Comment: The only trick I have remaining is that the YelpAPI is in Objective-C still so when I subclass YLPBusiness and try to modify the description() func... I am receiving the error, "Method 'description()' with Objective-C selector 'description' conflicts with getter for 'description' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C selector"

Comment: and if I try to add the "override" in front of it, I receive the error... "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: @Wade Sellers Please take a look at my updated answer, that should help you.

Comment: That did it @KlimczakM  Thank you so much for the help and explaining that.

Answer (score 3):

When you print an object you are actually invoking the object's `description` method.  It seems that the `YLPBusiness` class does not implement this method.  You could create an extension to `YLPBusiness` that implemented the `description` method.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the clarification!